# How can i create a hover animation during another hover animation in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class, hover

I'm trying to add two hover animations to each image in my photo galleries. Basically, when you hover over an image, I'd like for there to be a text that shows up in a black overlay and when you hover over that text, it becomes underlined. Essentially, I'd like it to look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAWpd.jpg
I know I have to create a hover element but the fact that I have two create two animations within each other really confuses me. Could anyone give me a few words of guidance?
Thanks!
Rowan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/98cHM/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id = 'pie' src = 'http://www.pieisgood.org/images/slice.jpg'><p id="pText" style='left:50px; top:50px; position:absolute;'>Text</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
#pie
{
    width:500px;
    height:265px;
    background-image:url('http://www.pieisgood.org/images/slice.jpg');
}

#pText
{
    display:none;
    transform:rotate(60deg);
    border:1px solid;
}

#pText:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#pie:hover > #pText
{
    display:block;
}
```

The **text** is hidden until you hover over the **div** with an ID of **pie.**  The `>` means it will effect the element after it if it is a child of `pie`.  It changes `display:none` on the paragraph to `display:block` while you're hovering over the image.  `#pText:hover` means when you hover over the paragraph, `text-decoration:underline` will **underline** the text while you're hovering over the **paragraph.**

Comment: Great, that gives me something to work with thanks! Just a couple of things, is it possible to have a black box around the text like in my example and also, is it possible to edit and rotate the text like I have shown? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3160616 Yes, and please accept my answer - use `transform:rotate` and `border: 1px solid` - answer edited and new fiddle created.

Comment: Ok great I get it now